# Issues with associative array and formatting

Tags: php, html, arrays

I've been attempting to create a dashboard with grafana embedded graphs. I've had some problems with formatting them which I believed was something I was coding incorrectly but after investigating and creating a different post about it here I've confirmed that this should and does output correctly all of my dashlets. My problem is that it is not displaying them, instead its only displaying the first one inside the array.

My code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
$dl = array
(
    'dashlet1' => array(
        'url' => 'http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=6',
        'height' => '200',
        'width' => '450'
    ),
    'dashlet2' => array(
        'url' => 'http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=7',
        'height' => '200',
        'width' => '450'
    ),
    'dashlet3' => array(
        'url' => 'http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=11',
        'height' => '200',
        'width' => '450'
    ),
    'dashlet4' => array(
        'url' => 'http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=4',
        'height' => '200',
        'width' => '350'
    ),
    'dashlet5' => array(
        'url' => 'http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=8',
        'height' => '200',
        'width' => '450'
    ),
    'dashlet6' => array(
        'url' => 'http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=10',
        'height' => '200',
        'width' => '450'
    ),
    'dashlet7' => array(
        'url' => 'http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=3',
        'height' => '200',
        'width' => '450'
    ),
    'dashlet8' => array(
        'url' => 'http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=5',
        'height' => '200',
        'width' => '350'
    )
);
foreach ($dl as $element) {
    $url = $element["url"];
    $height = $element["height"];
    $width = $element["width"];

    echo "<iframe src=\"" . $url . "\"" . " height=\"" . $height . "\" " . "width=\"" . $width . "\"" . " frameborder=\"0\">" . " " . "<\iframe>" . "\n";
```

My output:

```
<iframe src="http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=6" height="200" width="450" frameborder="0"> &lt;\iframe&gt;
&lt;iframe src="http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=7" height="200" width="450" frameborder="0"&gt; &lt;\iframe&gt;
&lt;iframe src="http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=11" height="200" width="450" frameborder="0"&gt; &lt;\iframe&gt;
&lt;iframe src="http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=4" height="200" width="350" frameborder="0"&gt; &lt;\iframe&gt;
&lt;iframe src="http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=8" height="200" width="450" frameborder="0"&gt; &lt;\iframe&gt;
&lt;iframe src="http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=10" height="200" width="450" frameborder="0"&gt; &lt;\iframe&gt;
&lt;iframe src="http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=3" height="200" width="450" frameborder="0"&gt; &lt;\iframe&gt;
&lt;iframe src="http://192.168.86.105:3000/dashboard-solo/db/home?panelId=5" height="200" width="350" frameborder="0"&gt; &lt;\iframe&gt;
</iframe>
```

[What I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6wO0.png)

Comment: `<\iframe>` should use `/` as `</iframe>`. Might be the issue.

Comment: Whatever you are using to display the output seems to be html encoding the subsequent data rows as it is putting them inside the first iFrame instead of creating new ones.
What is the code that is displaying this?

Comment: show all the code ..  the part you provided  is not enough ..

Answer (score 0):

Check modified foreach loop:

```
foreach ($dl as $element) {
    $url = $element["url"];
    $height = $element["height"];
    $width = $element["width"];

    echo "<iframe src=\"{$url}\" height=\"{$height}\" width=\"{$width}\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>\n";
}
```

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as approved then?

Comment: Done, sorry for the delay.